# Write a loop inside a filter function in {dplyr}

Tags: r, dplyr

UPDATED QUESTION :
I'm trying to write a loop with a filter() function in {dplyr} but it doesn't work.
Someone has an idea ?
Many thanks !

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
final <- iris %>%
  {for (type in c("Petal","Sepal")) filter(.,!!sym(paste0(type,".Length"))>5)}

# What I would like :
iris %>% 
  filter(!!sym("Petal.Length")>5) %>% 
  filter(!!sym("Sepal.Length")>5)
```

Comment: why a loop? you can do - `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length), sum, .names = 'Total_{col}'))
`

Comment: Because I need to use character values ("Petal" and "Sepal") in a more complicated example (a shiny app using inputs), even if your solution works well in this simple case

Comment: `across` works with character values as well. Can you please update your question with your actual use case?

Comment: I updated the question with a filter() function closest to my use case. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation can be improved further I think but since we don't have the complete use case here this will work for the information shared.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- iris
cols <- c("Petal","Sepal")
for(type in cols) {
  df <- df %>% filter(.data[[paste0(type, '.Length')]] > 5)
}

#Check with expected output
iris %>% 
  filter(!!sym("Petal.Length")>5) %>% 
  filter(!!sym("Sepal.Length")>5) -> res1

identical(res1, df)
#[1] TRUE
```